# Need to iterate for loop over multiple data sets in R

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics, anova

I've been having trouble finding a concise way to iterate a one way anova over multiple data frames in R.
All of the data frames I'm using have the same formatting but I was trying to figure out how to put them all into a list and then select a variable within the data to select for the anova. The code I was trying to use is below and I'm needing a bit of guidance on how to actually set up a for loop to iterate over a list of data frames to save me time rewriting/pasting the same code over and over when all I need to change is the data frame.

```
df<- list(data.1, data.2, data.3, etc)
#treatment and output are examples of my column titles
for(i in df)
{ 
oneway <- aov(df[i[Treatment]] ~ output, data = df[i]) }
```

I was expecting it to let me select a column within the data frame in the list but it hasn't been working.
I'm new to using r and welcome any and all recommendations!

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there are more elegant solutions, but if you wanted to stick with `for` loops, you could try the below, where I used the default `iris` data to run an `aov()` for `Species` across all columns.

```
# data
data.1 <- data.2 <- data.3 <- iris
ll <- list(data.1, data.2, data.3)

oneway <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(ll))

for(x in seq_along(ll)){
  for (y in names(ll[[x]])[-5]){
    oneway[[x]][[y]] <- aov(ll[[x]][[y]] ~ ll[[x]][["Species"]], data = ll[[x]])
  }
}
```

The result is a nested list with the outer list having a length of 3 (number of data sets) and each inner list having a length of 4 (the number of columns minus `Species`).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit shorter solution using data from @jpsmith's answer:

```
data.1 <- data.2 <- data.3 <- iris
df <- list(data.1, data.2, data.3)

result <- lapply(df, function(x) apply(x[,-5], 2, function(y) aov(y ~ Species, data = x)))
```